# The form $w_p(x,y) = \frac{(x-a)\,dy-(y-b)\,dx}{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}$ is exact $\iff$ $\exists$ angle function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

> Given $p=(a,b)\in\mathbb{R^2}$, show that the $1$-form
>   $w_p:\mathbb{R^2}-\{p\}\to (\mathbb{R^2})^*$, defined by
>
> $$w_p(x,y) = \frac{(x-a)\,dy-(y-b)\,dx}{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}$$
>
> is closed. Prove that this form is exact in an open $U\subset
>  \mathbb{R^2}-\{p\}$ if and only if there exists a continuous function
>   (necessairly $C^\infty$) $\theta_p:U\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $\cos
>  \theta_p (z) = \frac{x-a}{|z-p|}$ and $\sin \theta_p (z) =
>  \frac{y-b}{|z-p|}$ for all $z=(x,y)\in U$. A function $\theta_p$ with
>   these properties is called angle-function of vertex $p$

My book says that a form $w= \sum a_i \, dx_i$, of class $C^1$, is closed when $\frac{\partial a_i}{\partial x_j} = \frac{\partial a_j}{\partial x_i}$

I know that

$$w_p(x,y) = \frac{(x-a)\,dy-(y-b)\,dx}{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2} = \frac{x-a}{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}\,dy - \frac{y-b}{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2} \, dx$$

so $a_1 = \frac{x-a}{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}$, $a_2 = \frac{y-b}{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}$, $x_1 = y, x_2 = x$, then:

$$\frac{\partial a_1}{\partial x_1} = \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{x-a}{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}\right) = -\frac{2(x-a)(y-b)}{((x-a)^2+(y-b)^2)^2} = \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{y-b}{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}\right) = \frac{\partial a_2}{\partial x_2}$$

and

$$\frac{\partial a_1}{\partial x_2} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{x-a}{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}\right) = \pm\frac{(y-b)^2-(x-a)^2}{((x-a)^2+(y-b)^2)^2} = \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{y-b}{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}\right) = \frac{\partial a_2}{\partial x_1}$$

(I think I misidentified $a_2$ by the negative signal because of [1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx%20%5Cfrac%7Bx-a%7D%7B(x-a)%5E2%2B(y-b)%5E2%7D) and [2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdy%20%5Cfrac%7By-b%7D%7B(x-a)%5E2%2B(y-b)%5E2%7D) but ok, lets continue...)

> Prove that this form is exact in an open $U\subset 
> \mathbb{R^2}-\{p\}$ if and only if there exists a continuous function
>   (necessairly $C^{\infty}$) $\theta_p:U\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $\cos 
>  \theta_p (z) = \frac{x-a}{|z-p|}$ and $\sin \theta_p (z) = 
>  \frac{y-b}{|z-p|}$ for all $z=(x,y)\in U$

There's a theorem in my book that says:

A form $w:U\to(\mathbb{R^n})^*$, of class $C^1$, is closed if and only if it is locally exact

- A form $w:U\to(\mathbb{R^n})^*$ is locally exact when every point of $U$ is cointained in an open where $w$ is exact

Based on this theorem, since $w$ is closed, we have that it is locally exact (exact on a restricted $U$, which is $\mathbb{R^2}-\{p\}$). BUT the exercise does not ask me to prove that it is exact. Instead, I must prove that iot is exact if and only if...

So how should I do it? Do I need to do something to jump from locally exact to exact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the exactitude of $\omega_p$, let us proceed by double implication.

- If $\omega$ is exact on $U$, then there exists a smooth map $\theta_p\colon U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that one has:
  $$\mathrm{d}\theta_p=\omega_p.$$
  Therefore, since $(\mathrm{d}x,\mathrm{d}y)$ is a basis of $(\mathbb{R}^2)^*$, one gets:
  $$\begin{align}\partial_x\theta_p&=\frac{-(y-b)}{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\arctan\left(\frac{y-b}{x-a}\right),\\\partial_y\theta_p&=\frac{x-a}{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\arctan\left(\frac{y-b}{x-a}\right).\end{align}$$
  **From there I don't really now how to continue. Hope someone else will put you one the right track.**
- Assume that $\theta_p$ is a smooth map fulfilling the requiremens,then by assumption, one has:
  $$\theta_p(x,y)\equiv\arctan\left(\frac{y-b}{x-a}\right)\bmod [2\pi].$$
  Whence, $\mathrm{d}\theta_p=\omega_p$ and the $1$-form $\omega_p$ is exact on the open set $U$.

Comment: Could you clarify the part about the congruency with tangent?

Comment: Sure, by assumption, one has: $$\tan(\theta_p(x,y))=\frac{\sin(\theta_p(x,y))}{\cos(\theta_p(x,y))}=\frac{y-b}{x-a}.$$
Whence the result taking the $\arctan$ and recalling that $\arctan\circ\tan=\textrm{id}$ only on $]-\pi/2,\pi/2[$.

Comment: Why is $dw_p = w_p$?

Comment: That was a typo, I meant $\mathrm{d}\theta_p=\omega_p$.